# External properties Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, spring-boot-configuration

I'm trying to get my spring boot project to use properties defined outside of project. I have tried the steps described in docs but I'm unable to get it to work.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

```
.
+- folder
   +- properties
      +- application.properties
   +- myproject
      +- src
```

I'm using this for VM options: `-Dspring.config.location=file:../properties/` but it's not working. I tried multiple values for `spring.config.location` with no success (I suppose the issue is from here).

Comment: #1. Try with the full qualified path on your VM options, example: `-Dspring.config.location=file:/app/config/properties/`.
#2. Try with the `--` option instead of VM options, example: `java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=file:../properties/`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I've an app which connects to Postgresql Database. I've my database connection details outside of my project which is in some centralized version control system. I'm using `bootstrap.properties` file in my app. I've configured in `bootstrap.properties` to fetch my database connection details at app startup.
For Example,

```
postgresql.database.url:${databaseUrl}
postgresql.database.username:${databaseUsername}
postgresql.database.password:${databasePassword}
```

I'm passing config keys as values in bootstrap.properties. During app runtime, it will fetch the corresponding values based on keys.